# Loop-free way to convert List<SObject> to List<Id> with preserved order

Tags: apex, map

The title says it all. I insert a List into the database and want to pass a list of its Ids in the same order as in the original list. As this test proved using the Map and List constructors does not do the job.

Is there a one-liner so that I don't have to loop over a list?

```
List<SObject> sobjectList = new List<SObject>();
sobjectList.addAll(SmartFactory.createSObjectList('Contact', false, 2));
sobjectList.addAll(SmartFactory.createSObjectList('Account', false, 2));
sobjectList.addAll(SmartFactory.createSObjectList('Opportunity', false, 2));
insert sobjectList;

List<Id> idList = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, SObject>(sobjectList).keySet());

for(Integer i=0; i<sobjectList.size(); i++) {
    Id expectedId = sobjectList.get(i).Id;
    Id actualId = idList.get(i);
    System.assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);   
}
```

**Note: When I say preserved order I DO NOT mean alphabetical order or anything like that. I mean it in that way that if SObject S1 is the first in the List, its Id also needs to be the first element in the id list.**

Comment: Why don't you fill the list in the `createSObjectList` method?

Comment: @Sergey - at the point where he's calling createSObjectList the objects haven't been inserted and so they don't have IDs...

Comment: @DougB Ahh right... Just overlooked `insert` over there :)

Comment: Java lacks some sort of map functionality (in the sense of map-reduce) and Apex inherits that. You could write an utility class with a static method for frequently used mappings.

Comment: Is there some very specific reason you need to retain order within the list? Because if not, you could just use the list-to-map functionality you're using to create a map of id-to-sobject and loop over the keyset fetching sobjects from the map for each iteration.

Comment: Yes there is a reason ;), Martin.

Comment: You cant share the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Here goes the WTF...

In theory it has no loops (apart from the display loop). In reality I won't be surprised if it fails with "regex too complex" error on bigger dataset.

There should be a nicer way with Pattern, Matcher and [negative look-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061651/java-regular-expression-match-everything-but) but I'm too sober for this today...

```
String text;
List<Account> accs = new List<Account> {
    new Account(Name = 'Acc 1'), 
    new Account(Name = 'Acc 2'), 
    new Account(Name = 'Acc 3')
};

//  text = JSON.serialize(Database.insert(accs));
// if you don't want to insert, just pretend the next line is the result
text = '[{"id":"001A000000zBF1UIAW","success":true,"errors":[]},{"id":"001A000000zBF1VIAW","success":true,"errors":[]},{"id":"001A000000zBF1WIAW","success":true,"errors":[]}]';
```

---

```
text = text.replaceAll('"id":|"success":true|"errors":|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}|\\"', '').replaceAll(',+', ',').removeEnd(',');
List<String> ids = text.split(',');

if(ids.size() != accs.size()){
    System.debug('Probably save has failed?');
} else {
    for(String s : ids){
        System.debug(s);
    }
}
```

I suspect it'll fail horribly when `Database.insert(list, false)` is used and one of rows fails. Up to you what you want in such scenario, null probably?

Comment: Weird, but cool ;)

Comment: This is interesting, but I would be concerned about hitting heap space errors on larger strings with it.

Comment: @PhilR If the insert is successful, `LEN({"id":"001A000000zBF1UIAW","success":true,"errors":[]},)` = 55 chars. Multiply by 200 max and you get bit over 10K while heap size is at least 3 MB. On failure of course it grows (don't know to how much, 200 * 1K? 5K sounds bit too long). It shouldn't be too bad on the heap, if anything I'd really suspect "regex too complicated" like http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/regex-too-complicated-error, http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Regex-too-complicated-error-for-large-volume-of-data-and-a/td-p/178769

Comment: if you can assume success (a terrible assumption), `text.replace('[{"id":"','').replace('","success":true,"errors":[]}]','').split('","success":true,"errors":[]},{"id":"')` will get it done without regex

Answer (score 2):

When you insert a list of sObjects all in one batch they will usually be assigned Ids sequentially. I don't think that this is guaranteed but in a testmethod where nothing else is happening concurrently I would expect it to always be the case.

In tried some quick tests with lists of various lengths and I wasn't able to get the records to insert out of order.

```
List<SObject> sobjectList = SmartFactory.createSObjectList('Contact', false, 5);
insert sobjectList;

List<Id> idList = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, SObject>(sobjectList).keySet());
idList.sort();

for(Integer i=0; i<sobjectList.size(); i++) {
    Id expectedId = sobjectList.get(i).Id;
    Id actualId = idList.get(i);
    System.assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);  
}
```

Comment: Really, the only difference between your code and mine is `idList.sort()`. But why in the world should I mix order by sorting it?!

Comment: Sorting it fixes order, since a `Map.keySet()` is a set, in which order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is this really true?! I'm 99% sure that this just sorts alphabetical and its a technical coincidence that ids are that way.

Comment: Greg: try it with fake ids or different objects and it will not work as sort has absolutelly nothing to do with preserving list order .

Comment: @Robert Sort is alphabetical. That's why I said that this only works when Ids are assigned sequentially (as they usually are). I'm not sure what you mean by sort "preserving list order". I agree that it won't work if you are inserting multiple sObject types from the same list.

Comment: So this is definitly not an answer to my question :(

Comment: @Robert no, not after you modified the question ;).