# regex too complicated error when using split function for less than 1M characters

Tags: apex, attachment, governorlimits, regular-expressions, string

I am working with an attachment in Salesforce.
this is a text file with 7291 rows and each row has 94 columns.

I am able to read this attachment record as "Attachment". 
I am also able to convert "Attachment" to String using Body.ToString()
function of the Attachment class.
After this I try to split the string using newline character using split function.

Here is where I get "regex too complicated" error.

I assume this error is because of the size of the string.
So I am trying to come up with a way to parse string without using split 
function.

I can do this using SubString function in a loop but for this I need
to know what is the string length to be able to stop the loop.

But I don't see a way to get string size in apex.

How can we do this ? Also any idea why Split is failing for string which has less than 1M characters ?

Below is the code -

```
public PageReference validateFile()
{
    //need to do validation
    String errormessage = '';
    validationPassed = true;

if(attachmentProperty != null && attachmentProperty.Body != null )
    {
        string attachmentBodyString = attachmentProperty.Body.toString();
    //above string populated correctly with attachment content

        List<string> modifiedfileLinesList = new List<string>();
        List<string> fileLinesList = attachmentBodyString.split('\n');

    //above split function is throwing an error

    //some logic here
}


}
```

Any insight into this would be great.

Comment: method `length()` on a string gets you the size.  I've had this problem myself in a CSV parser and ended up looking for the first newline that wasn't enclosed in double quotes (all with in a loop)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea why split would error out for string having < 1M characters ?

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/regex-too-complicated-error ; see http://frombelvideres4thfloor.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ietf-rfc-4180-compliant-csv-reader-for.html for an apex csv parser

Answer (score -2):

if(attachmentProperty != null && attachmentProperty.Body != null )
    {
        string attachmentBodyString = attachmentProperty.Body.toString();
        //above string populated correctly with attachment content

```
    List<string> modifiedfileLinesList = new List<string>();
    List<string> fileLinesList = new List<String>();
    while(attachmentBodyString != '')
    {
         fileLinesList.add(attachmentBodyString.substring(0,attachmentBodyString.firstIndexOf('\n')));
         attachmentBodyString = attachmentBodyString.substring(attachmentBodyString.firstIndexOf('\n'), attachmentBodyString.length());
    }
```

attachmentBodyString.split('\n');

```
//above split function is throwing an error

//some logic here
```

}

Comment: (1) How does this answer the question about too-complex regex on very long strings? (2) Code is not formatted